# Oops! Mixed up Multiplication - Needs to be Fixed

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

$Given$:

$U$, $V$, $C$ are distinct digits, varying from 1 to 9.

$U$ > $V$ > $C$

$UVC$, $VCU$, $CUV$ are concatenated Numbers

$(UVC)*(VCU)*(CUV)$ = $234235286$

The digits on the right hand side are mixed up except 6 in the units place.

By deducing the digits $U$, $V$,$C$ , please restore the correct number on the right hand side.

Comment: I will wait at least few hours to comment on any answer to see who has best outline of the logical path to final deduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By trial and error:

> 983 x 839 x 398 = 328245326 -> 234235286
>  I tried few combinations and found that - it can't be with 1, 5, 6 and 7
>  5 because number would end with 0 or 5
>  1 because at least one number would be 1 (199*999*999 starts with 1)
>  6 (and 7) because it needs another 6 to end with 6 = 2 x 3 or 3 x 7 and it is not correct number combination.
>  Also numbers can't have sum divisible by 3